# Accessing an object from a JSON array of objects yields "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm using a Blockspring API that returns a JSON array of objects (read in from a Google Sheet).  However, whenever I try to access an object from the array, an "undefined" value is returned.  I have attached the code and the console log below.  Does anyone have any ideas why?

```
blockspring.runParsed("query-public-google-spreadsheet", { "query": "SELECT A, B, C", "url": 
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYvcYf_41aghdXRSpg25TKW4Qj9p1Lpz92b1xG-9R1Q/edit?usp=sharing"}, 
    { "api_key": "br_50064_1fe91fe1478ef990dc8b5e9b4041c2c476670306" }, function(res){  
        var obj=res.params;
        console.log(obj);
        var temp=obj[0];
        console.log(temp);
    }
```

[image: Console Output]

Comment: See *"I'm trying to access a property but I get only `undefined` back?"* in the accepted answer of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `obj.data[0]` to access the first element of an array.

Looking at your output in the console, it seems you are missing the `data` property of `obj`.

Object `obj` doesn't have a property with name `0` so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to play around with it myself but I can tell that the problem is just how you are accessing the info.

When you try to grab the data with `var temp=obj[0]` you are treating object like an array when is it not. I would recommend trying to grab the data using this:

```
//get the actual array
JSONArray theArray = obj.getJSONArray("data"); //I believe it is stored in an array called data... could be that the obj is just fine
// now get the first element:
JSONObject firstItem = theArray.getJSONObject(0);
// and so on
String name = firstItem.getString("Name"); // A
```

You most likely can grab it using var `temp = obj.data[0];`

Comment: This question is about JavaScript, not Java (your assessment is still correct though).